# Dropdown filter in ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using 'ag-grid-angular' in my project.

[image]

This is what the filter looks like currently. I want a drop-down instead of a search box. Additionally, I want to place the unique elements present in that column to be in the drop-down values. How can I implement this functionality?

I've tried using 'IFilterAngularComp' but it is not working.

Comment: Are you using Enterprise edition?  Is this what you are looking for? https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#top

Comment: I am using the community edition. The requirement was for a drop-down but set-filter will also work as it achieves the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use agSetColumnFilter instead of dropdown filter , actually ag grid not provided dropdown filter its provide different filter plz check

https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/filtering/

Comment: The set filter is only for the enterprise version. I was looking for a way to do it in the free version.